# Is there a word for the sum of society's law, moral value and personal beliefs?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the sum of society's law, moral value and personal beliefs?

a word if I do it, I can't be wrong, won't go to jail.

Like no stealing, no raping, no bullying family members,stay postive, always happy,  do well at school...
Anything long as it equals to what I should do

Comment: Law, moral values, and personal beliefs cover a vast amount more than "thou shalt nots". The best word that fits what you asked for is _culture_.

Comment: @John Lawler I want a first person perspective word.

Comment: _My culture_, then.

Comment: What are society's personal beliefs? The notion seems self-contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of society's law, moral value and personal beliefs could be called its

> [**ethos**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ethos)
>   NOUN
>
> The characteristic spirit of a culture, era, or community as manifested in its attitudes and aspirations.
>   *Their projects are diverse, but the firms share a similar ethos.*

---

Another word is

> [**values**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/value)
>   NOUN
>
> Principles or standards of behaviour; one's judgement of what is important in life.
>   *Today, principled values and beliefs are notably absent.*

<sub>From Lexico.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be personal [ethics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics).

> Ethics seeks to resolve questions of human morality by defining concepts such as good and evil, right and wrong, virtue and vice, justice and crime. As a field of intellectual inquiry, moral philosophy also is related to the fields of moral psychology, descriptive ethics, and value theory.

Comment: Ethics covers only moral beliefs, not the law and 'personal beliefs' (whatever the latter is). Some of the law is based on ethics, but it is always conceptually distinct from it.