# A word meaning the general belief of a specific time period

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember learning this in art history class but for the life of me I can't remember. The word is synonymous with common sense. Like the belief or thought was so widely believed that it was believed to be a given fact but only in that time period.

For example, it was once common sense for people to have slaves.

My searches in the thesaurus return results with words meaning "sound judgement" or of that nature which is what I'm not looking for. Im looking for a word that's more objective, almost clinical?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the word **ethos** will do. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ethos) has

> **ethos**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> The characteristic spirit of a culture, era, or community as manifested in its attitudes and aspirations.
> *Moving with the times is very much part of the ethos of the magazine, and of course we must practise what we preach.*

So a critic might say

> In the ethos of those times, human life counted for little.

There are synonyms to be found: ideology, standards, mindset etc.

Comment: Maybe even conventional wisdom.

Comment: Not only is OP a duplicate, but so is [your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516245/is-there-a-word-for-the-sum-of-societys-law-moral-value-and-personal-beliefs/516250#516250). How is this in accord with ELU's aim to have a single definitive answer to valid questions?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had forgotten about it. Had I remembered, I would have flagged it.

Comment: So please delete here.

Answer (score 2):

Zeitgeist is what you are looking for

> the general intellectual, moral, and cultural climate of an era

His songs perfectly captured the zeitgeist of 1960s America.

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_bias

**Cultural bias** is the phenomenon of interpreting and judging phenomena by standards inherent to one's own culture. The phenomenon is sometimes considered a problem central to social and human sciences, such as economics, psychology, anthropology, and sociology. Some practitioners of the aforementioned fields have attempted to develop methods and theories to compensate for or eliminate cultural bias.

Cultural bias occurs when people of a culture make assumptions about conventions, including conventions of language, notation, proof and evidence. They are then accused of mistaking these assumptions for laws of logic or nature. Numerous such biases exist, concerning cultural norms for color, mate selection, concepts of justice, linguistic and logical validity, the acceptability of evidence, and taboos.

Possibly, "implicit bias"?